# javascript not executed unless empty <script> tag included

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

test.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-main="app" src="require.js" />
    <div id="box">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and app.js:

```
require(["domReady"], function (dom_ready) {
    dom_ready( function () {
        document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = 'test';
    });
});
```

I dropped the require.js and domReady.js files in the same directory:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/requirejs/domReady/latest/domReady.js
- http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.11/minified/require.js

My browser does not display the "test" string in the webpage when I open it (tried with FF and chromium).

However, the "test" string is displayed if I add an empty  tag:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-main="app" src="require.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="box">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: You didn't close first script tag so second just closing the first. You can't put slash on the end of script tag, it's not selfclosing tag.

Comment: I was under the impression that script tags could be empty (<script />) but the HTML spec says no, indeed: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Close the script-tag properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="app" src="require.js"></script>
```